# Writing a BFS Search Algorithm by Hand

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph, breadth-first-search

I am trying to learn more about search algorithms for network graphs. To illustrate this, I created the following example.

**Step 1:** Suppose there are 100 countries (country_1....country_100) that are randomly connected to each other

```
set.seed(123)


library(igraph)


countries <- paste0("country_", 1:100)


g <- make_empty_graph(100)


num_edges <- 200
edge_list <- sample(countries, size = num_edges * 2, replace = TRUE)
edge_list <- matrix(edge_list, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edge_list, directed = FALSE)


V(g)$name <- countries

plot(g, vertex.label.cex = 0.7, vertex.label.color = "black", vertex.label.dist = 2)
```

**Step 2:** Now, suppose 20 people (person_A...person_T) live in these countries (each country can only have at most one person - 80 of the countries will be empty):

```
edge_list <- as_edgelist(g)

df <- as.data.frame(edge_list)

colnames(df) <- c("from", "to")

people <- paste0("person_", LETTERS[1:20])

assignment <- sample(countries, size = length(people), replace = FALSE)
names(assignment) <- people

df2 <- data.frame(country = countries)


df2$person <- ifelse(df2$country %in% assignment, names(assignment)[match(df2$country, assignment)], "empty")
```

**Step 3:** As an optional step, we can visualize the results:

```
library(visNetwork)

df2$color <- ifelse(df2$person == "empty", "grey", "red")

df2$label <- ifelse(df2$person == "empty", df2$country, paste0(df2$person, "\n", df2$country))

nodes <- data.frame(id = df2$country, label = df2$label, color = df2$color)

edges <- df

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
    visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)
```

[image]

**My Problem:** Suppose we take "person_A" - I want to find out who is the nearest person to "person_A" and which country this person lives in. **I am interested in learning how to write a BFS algorithm for this problem by hand** - for example: take person_A and search everyone in a radius of degree1 - if no one is found, now search everyone in a radius of degree2 ... continue until you find the first person(s).

I know how to use a pre-built implementation of this algorithm :

```
adj_matrix <- as_adjacency_matrix(g)

diag(adj_matrix) <- 0

shortest_paths <- shortest.paths(g)

df2_filtered <- subset(df2, person != "empty")
selected_countries <- intersect(rownames(shortest_paths), df2_filtered$country)

filtered_paths <- shortest_paths[selected_countries, selected_countries]

item = df2[df2$person %in% c("person_A"), ]

#answer (exclude distance = 0, i.e. the same country itself)
sort(filtered_paths[rownames(filtered_paths) == item$country, ])[2]
```

**Can someone please show me how I could write a search algorithm (by hand) to accomplish this task which starts with a person's name - and then prints the results of the search at each step until a person is found?**

Comment: I don't think you should use the word `degree` here. You should use `order`, see arguments in `ego`. And also, your question seems not related to BFS but just finding the valid neighbors, thus being confusing when reading the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

I don't think you are looking for BFS but just the `ego` networks defined by the nearest valid neighbors. Probably you can try the code below

```
f <- function(p, df = df2, graph = g) {
    v <- df %>%
        filter(person == p) %>%
        select(country) %>%
        pluck(1)

    nulls <- df2 %>%
        filter(person == "empty") %>%
        select(country) %>%
        pluck(1)

    pers <- df2 %>%
        filter(person != "empty")

    d <- distances(graph, v, setdiff(names(V(graph)), c(v, nulls)))
    split(pers$person[match(colnames(d), pers$country)], d)
}
```

such that

```
> f("person_A")
$`2`
[1] "person_N" "person_K"

$`3`
[1] "person_C" "person_E" "person_I"

$`4`
[1] "person_P" "person_M" "person_Q"

$`5`
[1] "person_J" "person_S" "person_O" "person_T" "person_G" "person_F" "person_R"
[8] "person_H"

$`6`
[1] "person_L"

$`7`
[1] "person_B"


> f("person_B")
$`2`
[1] "person_F"

$`3`
[1] "person_S" "person_G"

$`4`
[1] "person_J" "person_P" "person_H"

$`5`
[1] "person_M" "person_N" "person_K" "person_T" "person_R" "person_E" "person_L"

$`6`
[1] "person_Q" "person_O" "person_C" "person_I"

$`7`
[1] "person_A"


> f("person_C")
$`1`
[1] "person_N"

$`3`
[1] "person_P" "person_M" "person_A" "person_K"

$`4`
[1] "person_J" "person_Q" "person_O" "person_G" "person_R" "person_H" "person_E"
[8] "person_I"

$`5`
[1] "person_S" "person_T" "person_F" "person_L"

$`6`
[1] "person_B"
```

---

## Previous

Not sure about your motivation and/or necessity of implementing the BFS algorithm by yourself, but I guess it is worthy to try `bfs` from `igraph` (since you are using `igraph` anyway in your question)

```
f <- function(p, df = df2, graph = g) {
    v <- df %>%
        filter(person == p) %>%
        select(country) %>%
        pluck(1)

    df %>%
        arrange(match(country, names(bfs(graph, v)$order))) %>%
        filter(person != "empty") %>%
        slice(2) %>%
        select(person) %>%
        pluck(1)
}
```

such that

```
> f("person_A")
[1] "person_N"

> f("person_B")
[1] "person_F"

> f("person_C")
[1] "person_N"
```

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to print the history of the search? (e.g. degree1 : no one found, degre2: no one found, degree3: person_j (country_2) and person_B (country_15) ?

Comment: @stats_noob do you want BFS? Or just the `ego` network? I am confused what you are really after

Comment: @stats_noob See my update, where the name in the output list, e.g., `2`, `3` and so on, indicates the distance to the valid neighbors.

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you so much for all your help! I am working on this (bountied) question and am stuck - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552054/r-how-to-prevent-overlapping-ranges-within-nested-summary-groups thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

### Background/Overview

The big picture idea of Breadth First Search is that you start at a point in a graph (let's call it `a`), and you add all of the neighbours to a list of unexplored points (which we'll call the `frontier`). You then go through the list, one by one, and for each point, you add the unseen neighbours of that point to the end of the queue, and so on, until you either find the point you are looking for (which could be a specific point `b`, or just any point which meets a certain criteria you've set), or alternatively you run out of places (because you've explored everywhere).

### Tidying the data

First, I'm going to clean up the data a bit. I create a dataframe which is just the people that exist (no empties):

```
people_df <- df2 %>% 
    filter(person != "empty") %>%
    select(person, country)
```

I then turn the country connections dataframe `df` into a dataframe `neighbours_df` which gives me the neighbours of each point. The way the dataframe was structured, it has (for example) a row:

> ```
>       from         to
> country_31 country_79
> ```

but none for the reverse, i.e.

> ```
>       from         to
> country_79 country_31
> ```

So I switch the columns, add the reversed ones onto the end of the first one, and group each point's neighbours into a list, to make it tidier:

```
reversed_df <- df %>% 
    mutate(new_from = to, to = from, from = new_from) %>% 
    select(from, to)

neighbours_df <- df %>% 
    bind_rows(reversed_df) %>% 
    filter(from != to) %>%
    group_by(from) %>%
    summarise(to = list(to))
    
#          from                            to
# 1    country_1   c("country_8", "country_92")
```

### Implementation

```
breadth_first_search <- function(person, neighbours_df, people_df) {
  # get the country of the person
    starting_country <- people_df$country[people_df$person == person]

  # initialise the visited list 
    visited <- c()

  # initialise the frontier with the starting point
    frontier <- list()
    frontier[[starting_country]] <- 0

  # initialise distance from start variable (so we can print how far we are from the start)
    distance_from_start <- 0

  # while the frontier is not empty
    while (length(frontier) > 0) {

      # get the first element of the frontier
        current <- names(frontier)[1]

      # get the distance from current to start
        distance_from_start <- frontier[[1]]
      
      print(paste0("Current point: ", current, " (", distance_from_start, " steps from start)"))

      # remove the first element of the frontier (the one we just selected)
        frontier <- frontier[-1]

        # if the current point is in the country column of our `people_df` (i.e. someone lives there), and it's not the starting country, return the person who lives there
        if (current %in% people_df$country && current != starting_country) {
          found_person <- people_df$person[people_df$country == current]
          print(paste0("Found person: ", found_person, ", " , distance_from_start , " steps from start, in country ", current))
            return(found_person)
        }

        # add the current point to the visited list
        visited <- c(visited, current)

        # get the neighbors of the current point
        neighbs <- neighbours_df$to[neighbours_df$from == current][[1]]

        # add the neighbors to the frontier if they haven't been visited already
        neighbs <- neighbs[!neighbs %in% visited]
        frontier <- c(frontier, setNames(rep(distance_from_start + 1, length(neighbs)), neighbs))
        }
    # if we search through all the points, and didn't find anyone, return NA
    return(NA)
}

print(breadth_first_search("person_R", neighbours_df, people_df))
# [1] "person_J"
```

### References / More Information

I'm cribbed fairly extensively from [this article](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html#python-breadth-first) by Red Blob Games (the companion to [this other piece](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html), which provides a great introduction to how breadth first search (and other similar graph search algorithms, like A* work). If you would like a more comprehensive take on how they work, the drawbacks and strengths of BFS, and/or want to play around with some interactive things, I would recommend checking that out!

Comment: @ Mark Hill: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to print the history of the search? (e.g. degree1 : no one found, degre2: no one found, degree3: person_j (country_2) and person_B (country_15) ?

Comment: @ Mark Hill: Thank you for your reply! I am comparing the solution that I wrote vs the one you provided and the one provided by @ThomasIsCoding - all 3 of seem to get different answers for "person_R" ! lol!

Comment: my approach (person_R): country_39 person_N

Comment: your approach: Found person: person_L, 2 steps from start, in country country_35

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding:" person_N"

Comment: the issue is probably that you have many different people who are two steps from person R, and no definitive order for looking at which order neighbours are added to the frontier. When I run my one, it gives different people sometimes. If there was only one person who was at the minimum number of steps away (i.e. there wasn't a tie), or you picked only one person as the goal, it wouldn't be an issue

Comment: I think I will try to perform a comparison of the 3 approaches...my approach uses the pre-built implementation , stores all distances in a  20x20 matrix - and this should tell us the actual closest person to any other person. From here, we can then compare both approaches to the real answer? Does this sound logical to you? Thank you so much!