# R: How to Prevent Overlapping Ranges Within (Nested) Summary Groups

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset on medical characteristics of patients and disease prevalance:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
status  <- as.factor(status )

height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
hospital_visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5000, replace = TRUE)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, gender, status, height, weight, hospital_visits, disease)

  Patient_ID gender    status   height    weight hospital_visits disease
1          1 Female   Citizen 145.0583 113.70725               1    TRUE
2          2   Male Immigrant 161.2759  88.33188              18   FALSE
3          3 Female Immigrant 138.5305  99.26961               6   FALSE
4          4   Male   Citizen 164.8102  84.31848              12    TRUE
5          5   Male   Citizen 159.1619  92.25090              12    TRUE
6          6 Female   Citizen 153.3513 101.31986              11    TRUE
```

**My Problem:** Based on this dataset, I am trying to calculate the disease proportions within "**nested groups**", i.e.

- First, select all males
- Then, select all male citizens
- Then, out of the set of all male citizens - identify a group of 20% of this set with the smallest heights
- Then, out of the set of all male citizens within the shortest 20% height - further isolate a group of 20% with the smallest weights
- Finally, out of the set of all male citizens within the shortest 20% height and within the shortest 20% height having the 20% smallest weight - further isolate them into a group with the 20% fewest number of hospital visits : **This will now be the first group**
- Repeat this process for all possible group combinations

**This means an individual patient can only belong to a single group - in other words, the groups can not have any overlapping ranges.**

In a previous question ([R: Merging a Lookup Table with a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551409/r-merging-a-lookup-table-with-a-data-frame)), I learned how to calculate the disease proportions within nested groups:

```
final = my_data |>
    group_by(gender, status) |>
    mutate(low_height = height < quantile(height, .2)) |>
    group_by(gender, status, low_height) |>
    mutate(low_weight = weight < quantile(weight, .2)) |>
    group_by(gender,  status, low_height, low_weight) |>
    mutate(low_visit = hospital_visits  < quantile(hospital_visits , .2)) |>
    group_by(gender, status, low_height, low_weight, low_visit) |>
    summarise(across(c(height, weight, hospital_visits),
                     ## list custom stats here:
                     list(min = \(xs) min(xs, na.rm = TRUE),
                          max = \(xs) max(xs, na.rm = TRUE)
                     ),
                     .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
    ),
    prop_disease = sum(disease)/n(),
    ## etc.
    )

final$low_height = final$low_weight = final$low_visit = NULL
```

**My Question** When I look at the results from this code:

```
> final
# A tibble: 32 x 9
# Groups:   gender, status [4]
   gender status    height_min height_max weight_min weight_max hospital_visits_min hospital_visits_max prop_disease
   <fct>  <fct>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>               <int>               <int>        <dbl>
 1 Female Citizen         142.       188.       82.3      119.                    4                  20        0.495
 2 Female Citizen         142.       175.       82.4      118.                    1                   3        0.495
 3 Female Citizen         142.       177.       57.4       82.3                   5                  20        0.482
```

- In row 1 and row 2: I can see that overlapping height ranges have been created such as (142,188) and (142, 175)
- This means that if a medical patient was 150 cm tall - the patient could be assigned to both of these groups: **as such, this violates the original condition of non-overlapping groups.**

**Can someone please show me if there is a way to fix this problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: Such overlaps must occur because height and weight quantiles are not perfectly linearily correlated: a small well-fed man might belong to the smallest 20% of your sample but well exceed the 20% treshold by weight. So you'd need to define a treshold function (of weight *and* height) which dissects the bivariate plane into (only) two parts: small-light vs. tall-heavy individuals. Perhaps the Body Mass Index in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as said in the comment by @I_O, I agree that height and weight may not be absolutely separated to avoid the overlap.

If you want want to have a summary of all combinations with `quantile(... < 0.2)` for the features of interest, probably you can try

```
df %>%
    group_by(gender, status) %>%
    group_map(~ {
        .x %>%
            filter(height < quantile(height, .2)) %>%
            filter(weight < quantile(weight, .2)) %>%
            filter(hospital_visits < quantile(hospital_visits, .2)) %>%
            summarise(
                across(c(height, weight, hospital_visits),
                    list(
                        min = \(xs) min(xs, na.rm = TRUE),
                        max = \(xs) max(xs, na.rm = TRUE)
                    ),
                    .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
                ),
                prop_disease = mean(disease),
                .by = c(gender, status)
            )
    }, .keep = TRUE) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  gender status  height_min height_max weight_min weight_max hospital_visits_min
  <fct>  <fct>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>               <int>
1 Female Citizen       123.       141.       70.7       80.6                   1
2 Female Immigr…       124.       140.       62.0       83.5                   2
3 Male   Citizen       125.       140.       66.7       79.8                   1
4 Male   Immigr…       130.       140.       68.4       81.1                   1
# ℹ 2 more variables: hospital_visits_max <int>, prop_disease <dbl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to add some clarifications regarding my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591864/r-understanding-the-filter-statement-within-dplyr - can you please take a look at if you have time? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob I don't have any idea about that question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too simple but to avoid overlapping we could use the quantile cuts for (height, weight, hospital visits) as a group, and not on each level separately:

For the male citizens we could do:

```
my_data %>% 
  filter(gender == "Male", status == "Citizen") %>% 
  mutate(rank_height = rank(height),
         rank_weight = rank(weight),
         rank_hospital_visits = rank(hospital_visits)) %>% 
  mutate(total_score = rank_height + rank_weight + rank_hospital_visits,
         group_number = ntile(total_score, 5)) %>% 
  mutate(prop_disease = mean(disease), .by = group_number)
```

This ensure the assignment of each patient to one group based on the rank of the **groups** (height, weight, hospital visits) instead of each single level.

```
  Patient_ID gender  status   height    weight hospital_visits disease rank_height rank_weight rank_hospital_visits total_score group_number prop_disease
1           4   Male Citizen 164.8102  84.31848              12    TRUE        1502         434                930.0      2866.0            4    0.4672897
2           5   Male Citizen 159.1619  92.25090              12    TRUE        1316         936                930.0      3182.0            5    0.5125000
3           8   Male Citizen 152.0362  87.67197               4   FALSE         933         667                286.5      1886.5            2    0.4579439
4          11   Male Citizen 143.9616  87.24376               7    TRUE         438         637                519.0      1594.0            1    0.4704050
5          13   Male Citizen 155.9949 100.89346               5   FALSE        1157        1381                362.5      2900.5            4    0.4672897
6          20   Male Citizen 136.0402  82.95463               2    TRUE         133         368                123.5       624.5            1    0.4704050
7          24   Male Citizen 138.7447  90.35814               3   FALSE         222         822                206.0      1250.0            1    0.4704050
8          25   Male Citizen 148.1227 100.64930               6   FALSE         682        1373                438.0      2493.0            3    0.4517134
9          26   Male Citizen 139.6196  84.32218               1   FALSE         260         435                 41.0       736.0            1    0.4704050
10         31   Male Citizen 149.8554  92.32891              15    TRUE         812         941               1159.5      2912.5            4    0.4672897
11         32   Male Citizen 155.4558  78.81120              18    TRUE        1131         204               1401.0      2736.0            4    0.4672897
12         33   Male Citizen 150.9811  75.29820              18    TRUE         877         113               1401.0      2391.0            3    0.4517134
13         34   Male Citizen 150.1760 120.35185               8    TRUE         829        1604                599.0      3032.0            4    0.4672897
14         55   Male Citizen 151.4056  92.70188              16    TRUE         894         969               1233.5      3096.5            4    0.4672897
15         59   Male Citizen 141.6127  86.62372              11   FALSE         342         597                846.0      1785.0            2    0.4579439
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample, it is supposed to be the solution for your first example, using `slice_min`.

```
my_data |> filter(gender=="Male",
                  status == "Citizen") |> 
  slice_min(height, prop= 0.2) |> 
  slice_min(weight, prop = 0.2) |> 
  slice_min(hospital_visits, prop = 0.2)
```

If that works out for the example, you could create either a mapping function or just a function to iterate over all possible outcomes

By combinations you mean the gender X status?
or you need to have top 20, then 20-40, then 40-60% of weight and such, which creates a 5 X 5 X 5 [height X weight X hospital) and i guess times gender X status ?