# Add a "total" group when plotting data by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope this is not a duplicate (sorry if it is). I have a dataframe coming from a survey where each row represent an individual, who has a sex and a score. So I can plot the distribution of scores by sex with this code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(
    sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 200, replace = TRUE),
    score = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE)
)

d %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=sex, y=score)) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1, color="dimgray") +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x="Sex", y="Score", title="Score by sex")
```

[image: Example plot]

Now, I would like to add a third boxplot-violin graph below these two, which would show the distribution among all individuals.
I can do this graph when I replace `aes(x=sex, y=score)` with `aes(x="All", y=score)`, but I would like to automate it and have it below the two others.

To put it another way, I would like a graphical version of this "Ensemble" column.

```r
> library(questionr)
> cprop(table(quant.cut(d$score, nbclass = 4), d$sex))

         Female Male  Ensemble
  [1,3)   22.7   17.5  20.0   
  [3,5)   23.7   23.3  23.5   
  [5,8)   25.8   31.1  28.5   
  [8,10]  27.8   28.2  28.0   
  Total  100.0  100.0 100.0
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this but I just can't find it (sorry if it sounds "too obvious").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution:

example data with dramatic score difference (to show it works)

```
d <- data.frame(
    sex = gl(2, 100, labels = c("Male", "Female")),
    score = c(rnorm(100, 10), rnorm(100, 20))
)
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=sex, y=score)) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_violin(aes(x = 'total')) +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1, color="dimgray") +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = 'total'), width=0.1, color="dimgray") +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x="Sex", y="Score", title="Score by sex")
```

[image: groups and total]

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I like your solution! However, is there a mean to control the order of categories? I'd like to make sure the "total" group always appear last (in my tries, it appears either first or last depending on the plots). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Create a copy of d and replace sex with ALL

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d_all <- d
d_all$sex <- "All"

bind_rows(d, d_all) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=sex, y=score)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, color="dimgray") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Sex", y="Score", title="Score by sex and All")
```

[image]

Comment: @ TarJae:  I have been working on this (bountied) question for a while and have been stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552054/r-how-to-prevent-overlapping-ranges-within-nested-summary-groups . Can you please take a look at it if you have time? Thank you so much!

Comment: I chose the @I_O's solution as it uses only ggplot functions without having to change the dataset itself, but I like your solution too, I'll keep it aside if I can't find how to order its categories. Thank you!