# R: Understanding the "filter" statement within DPLYR

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
status  <- as.factor(status )

height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
hospital_visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5000, replace = TRUE)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, gender, status, height, weight, hospital_visits, disease)
```

Using the filter statement, I ran the following code which subsets the data by different ranges of hospital visits relative to a given combination of gender, status, height and weight:

```
inputs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1)
max = length(inputs)
limit = max - 1

my_list = list()

for (i in 1:limit)

{

   my_list[[i]] = my_data %>%
        filter(gender == "Male") %>%
        filter(status == "Citizen") %>%
        filter(between(height, quantile(height, 0), quantile(height, 0.2))) %>%
        filter(between(weight, quantile(weight, 0), quantile(weight, 0.2))) %>%
        filter(between(hospital_visits, quantile(hospital_visits, inputs[i]), quantile(hospital_visits, inputs[i+1]))) %>%
        summarize(
            gender = first(gender),
            status = first(status),
            min_height = min(height),
            max_height = max(height),
            min_weight = min(weight),
            max_weight = max(weight),
            min_hospital_visits = min(hospital_visits),
            max_hospital_visits = max(hospital_visits),
            disease_count = sum(disease),
            total_count = n(),
            disease_proportion = mean(disease)
        )

}
```

**My Question** : When I look at the results of the above code:

```
[[1]]
  gender  status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight min_hospital_visits max_hospital_visits disease_count total_count disease_proportion
1   Male Citizen    123.072   139.5564   63.57166   80.10757                   1                   3             7          14                0.5

[[2]]
  gender  status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight min_hospital_visits max_hospital_visits disease_count total_count disease_proportion
1   Male Citizen    123.072   140.1058   63.57166   80.86971                   3                   7            10          21          0.4761905

[[3]]
  gender  status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight min_hospital_visits max_hospital_visits disease_count total_count disease_proportion
1   Male Citizen   124.0888   141.0246   64.96209   80.66031                   7                  11            10          15          0.6666667

[[4]]
  gender  status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight min_hospital_visits max_hospital_visits disease_count total_count disease_proportion
1   Male Citizen    125.746   140.9952    74.1879   81.02482                  12                  14             8          14          0.5714286

[[5]]
  gender  status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight min_hospital_visits max_hospital_visits disease_count total_count disease_proportion
1   Male Citizen   129.9928   140.3866   64.80396   80.82552                  14                  20             8          16                0.5
```

**I notice that the ranges of height and weight are different each time - even though I am selecting the same ranges of height and weight each time.**

I am trying to "hierarchically filter" the dataset:

- first take all males
- then all all male citizens
- then 20% of the shortest male citizens
- then 20% of the lightest within the group of the 20% shortest male citizens
- then out of the 20% of the lightest within the group of the 20% shortest male citizens - find those with the 20% fewest number of hospital visits
- then calculate the disease rate

After doing this:

- first take all males
- then all all male citizens
- then 20% of the shortest male citizens
- then 20% of the lightest within the group of the 20% shortest male citizens
- then out of the 20% of the lightest within the group of the 20% shortest male citizens - find those with the 20%-40% fewest number of hospital visits
- then calculate the disease rate

And keep repeating this process until you reach 80%-100% hospital visits. **This means that the ranges on height and weight should not change.**

**Is there a way to accomplish this using the "filter" statement in R?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you think the range will not change when you are selecting different records each time. If the shortest person had a hospital_visits in the first quintile, they would only be included in that subset and not the others. Thus the other subset will have to have a different minimum height value.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the ranges on height and weight should not change.

But they should. In each iteration, you are selecting a different subset of the data based on hospital visits. It would be extremely unlikely to have the exact same height quantiles (up to the 3rd decimal) in different subsets of the data.